# Mysql - select multiple columns with same value and other colums equal to zero

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query that selects the records where col1 and col2 = 4 and col3 or col4 = 0

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 4 IN(col1, col2) && (col3 = 0 || col4 = 0)
```

The or is not working.  It returns zero rows and I know that there are 4

Comment: Show your sample dataset

Comment: Should be `WHERE col1=4 AND col2=4 AND (col3=0 OR col4=0)`

Answer (score 3):

&& and || in SQL are AND and OR.

Rewrite that to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (col1 = 4 AND col2 = 4) AND (col3 = 0 OR col4 = 0)
```

You can't use IN for column names. You can use IN like this:
`WHERE col3 IN('4','a','another valid value')`,
which is equals to `WHERE (col3 = '4' OR col3 = 'a' OR ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try like below instead cause per your posted code `4 IN (col1, col2)` will be `col1=4 or col2 = 4` whereas you want it to be `and` condition

Per last comment update; below query will get you exactly those records

> There is a total of 4 rows where column1 or column2 = 4. of those
>   rows  I only want to return the rows where col3 or col4 = zero

```
SELECT * 
FROM test4 
WHERE (col1 = 4 or col2 = 4) 
and (col3 = 0 or col4 = 0)
```

Comment: still returns empty query

Comment: nope.  Your query will return all 4.  But when I change the value of either col3 or col4 to 1, it will still return all 4

Comment: @user2091928, what's desired output then?

Comment: There is a total of 4 rows where column 1 or column 2 = 4. of those rows I only want to return the rows where col3 or col4 = zero.

Comment: @user2091928, mind trying again. See edited answer. Also, what you mentioned in comment is not same as what you said in your original post.

Comment: @user2091928, can't help further without seeing your sample data; cause the query I given actually works fine.

Comment: does it matter that col3 & col4 are enum type "1","0"?