# Column name as Boolean? What does it mean?

Tags: mysql, boolean

I'm trying to wrap my head around an MySQL statement that I thought would behave differently than it actually does. But I feel like the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) is [sending](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html) me [in circles](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or).

---

This is what I want, basically …

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = 'string' OR col2 = 'string' OR col3 = 'string';
```

… instead that I'd like to avoid the repetition of the never-changing `'string'`. A few days ago I discovered that this works …

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 OR col2 OR col3 = 'string';
```

… or, that it at least returned *some* rows. I was assuming that these two statements are the same – it certainly seemed so on first sight.

But today I found out that the interpreter reads this as …

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (col1 OR col2) OR (col3 = 'string');
```

Now I'm wondering what `(col1 OR col2)` actually means. Can someone please enlighten me? I can't find a clear answer in SO or via Google.

The [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) says this …

> Logical OR. When both operands are non-NULL, the result is 1 if any operand is nonzero, and 0 otherwise. With a NULL operand, the result is 1 if the other operand is nonzero, and NULL otherwise. If both operands are NULL, the result is NULL.

… but then I don't get the difference between `id OR name` and `name OR owner` (see appendix).

#### Appendix

```
MariaDB [test2]> select * from pets;
+----+------------+-------+
| id | name       | owner |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | dog        | pete  |
|  2 | cat        | erica |
|  3 | bird       | maria |
|  4 | koala bear | pete  |
|  5 | gorilla    | joe   |
|  6 | chamaelon  | NULL  |
|  7 | NULL       | joe   |
+----+------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test2]> select * from pets WHERE name;
Empty set, 6 warnings (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test2]> select * from pets WHERE name OR owner;
Empty set, 12 warnings (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test2]> select * from pets WHERE id OR name OR owner;
+----+------------+-------+
| id | name       | owner |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | dog        | pete  |
|  2 | cat        | erica |
|  3 | bird       | maria |
|  4 | koala bear | pete  |
|  5 | gorilla    | joe   |
|  6 | chamaelon  | NULL  |
|  7 | NULL       | joe   |
+----+------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [test2]> select * from pets WHERE id OR name OR owner = 'joe';
+----+------------+-------+
| id | name       | owner |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | dog        | pete  |
|  2 | cat        | erica |
|  3 | bird       | maria |
|  4 | koala bear | pete  |
|  5 | gorilla    | joe   |
|  6 | chamaelon  | NULL  |
|  7 | NULL       | joe   |
+----+------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test2]> select * from pets WHERE (id OR name);
+----+------------+-------+
| id | name       | owner |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | dog        | pete  |
|  2 | cat        | erica |
|  3 | bird       | maria |
|  4 | koala bear | pete  |
|  5 | gorilla    | joe   |
|  6 | chamaelon  | NULL  |
|  7 | NULL       | joe   |
+----+------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is standard operator precedence. The first test (col1 or col2) is a complete comparison, as is `col3 = 'string'`. `col1 or col2 or col3` is valid until you add `= 'string'`, which is not valid on it's own. The parser then backs up until it finds `col3 = 'string'`, which is valid, The expression then parses as `(col1 or col2) or (col3 = 'string')`. You should find a SQL reference or tutorial and read up on operator precedence, which is the way that operators are processed when being parsed.

Comment: @RyanVincent I thought [that isn't allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24045801/2126442).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'string' IN (col1, col2, col3)
```

Because no value in your `name` column evaluates to 1, `id OR name` in your case evaluates to 1, which means your query is the same as

```
select * from pets WHERE 1
```

Similarly, because no value in your `owner` column evaluates to 1, `name OR owner` evaluates to 0, which means your query is the same as

```
select * from pets WHERE 0
```

I suggest `select`-ing the expression first before using it in the `where` clause, so you can see what value is going to be used.

Example:

```
select name OR owner
```

Comment: "SELECTing the expression first" » I didn't even know that was possible. Great advice!